# Правильно ли расставлены запятые при сравнении?

Tags: сравнительный-оборот

Правильно ли расставлены запятые в предложении?

*Из разноцветных галстуков «удав»,

Длиною, как советская подлодка*

Answer (score 1):

*Из разноцветных галстуков «удав»,*

*ДлинОю, **как советская подлОдка**.*

**Распространенный** сравнительный оборот обособляется: такой длиною, как советская подлодка.

Сравнить: *рыбки длиной в (с) ладонь, рыбки длиной как ладОнь*. Нераспространенный оборот может быть необособленным обстоятельством.

Answer (score 1):

Да, правильно. Сравнение + дополнение

Comment: Andrew, мне кажется, что здесь сравнение входит в обособленное  несогласованное определение: удав (кокой) длиною, как советская подлодка. Или можно так: удав, длинный, как советская подлодка.

Comment: А я думаю нет. Я красивый, как статуя свободы:)

Comment: А про удава-то  забыли?  Он тоже красивый, да еще и длинный. Там такое предложение: Из разноцветных галстуков «удав», длинный, как советская подлодка